# Unable to access .exe from old HDD

Tags: windows-10, security, filesystems, file-permissions

I have recently installed an SSD with new Windows 10 Pro. My previous hard drive is also attached to my new SSD windows installation as portable drive. Everything was going fine except I was unable to share files on previous HDD over network. I ignored this minor problem and proceeded to install software using setups present in my previous HDD. I was able to install those programs directly from my HDD, but now I am unable to run executables from my HDD partition directly. When I execute them I get "Windows cannot access specified device, path, or file. You may have inappropriate permission to access them."

Before this problem occurred Windows Defender gave me a warning about a false positive. I even tried to disable windows defender, add files to exclusion list but it still didn't work. Also, I tried to change security setting of executables to give `Full Control` to `Everyone` but this still doesn't resolve issue. I also tried to attach this HDD to my other PC and this problem also exist there. I am able to run other files from my HDD include .MP4, .zip, .rar, .msi, etc. Problem seems to be only occurring with .exe files.

Note that if I copy these executable to my boot ssd drive I am able to run these executables. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Take ownership of old drive and include subfolders... go for coffe

Comment: I already took ownership of that exe i am trying to run

Comment: Also any DLL's etc used by exe in same folder If app tries to write a config file and cant because of permissions granted on old system and not installed properly and on this system. it may fail without ownership and permissions

Comment: Its just exe. I am testing it on fillezilla setup exe. I just noticed that it is also not working for my usb flash drive. I forgot to mention that I have attached my HDD as portable drive